# Excel - Formula to find value on spreadsheet plus its status in another column

Tags: excel

I have a list of 60,000+ Meters with status'. I'd like to paste a list of meters from another source and plug in a value to tell me what the status is for that meter automatically instead of searching each one.

For example:

If I was asked "What is the status for 4972617, 4869966, and 4822118" and had the list in excel form, I'd like to dump them in a column of their own and apply a formula to tell me it found the meter and it's notation is exchanged! Something I would place in G3 in my example below...

LIST:

```
COLUMN A        COLUMN B                  COLUMN F    COLUMN G
Status           Meter                     Search      
Exchanged       4972617                   4972617     =????
Exchanged       4869966                   4869966
Open            4822118                   4822118   
Exchanged       5020631
Exchanged       4954834
Open            1337554
Open            5148459
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can switch column A and B, you can use `VLOOKUP` like this in cell G2:

```
=VLOOKUP(F2, A:B, 2, FALSE)
```

And then copy/paste the formula down.

If you cannot switch columns A and B, you will have to use `INDEX` and `MATCH` like this:

```
=INDEX(A:A, MATCH(F2, B:B, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

`VLOOKUP` will do your bidding.

Say your meters are in column A and the statuses are in column B.

Type in the meters you want to search for in column F, as you have them.

In G1, put in this:

```
=VLOOKUP(C1, A:B, 2, FALSE)
```

And fill down as far as you need.  This will put the corresponding status next to the meter ID.

But, if you're doing a lot of queries like this, I'd learn how to use Microsoft Access.

Comment: What does access provide, a report from an excel file?

Comment: It's a relational database.  If you're going to be "asking questions" of your data, you'll be able to get answers to more kinds of questions faster if you use a relational database.  If you bought MS Office rather than just Excel by itself, you already have it.

Comment: I do have Access. Does it work well as a CRM type program? We are looking to search and use an Excel database but for a call center to update status on accounts and make appointments from. Searching excel and using it for attempt note taking is dizzying.